# Trimming begining of string in VB forms application

Tags: vb.net, string

Here is an example of the string / variable i want to trim:

```
type="game" music-file="my-file.mp3" gts="false"
```

I would like to **find** the beginning / end of the following code and **trim them** off.
I do **not** know the string before / after, so i am **not** able to use `replace("String", "")` functions.
How would i trim the string to make it only show: `music-file="my-file.mp3`?

1. I would like the **string** to go into a **text box**.
2. I would like to trim the beginning **and** end if possible.
3. I would **NOT** like to use external libraries (**DLLS**)

Comment: Not a lot to go on, but it almost looks like the string could be json

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, that is correct. the string i am trying to cut from is json.

Comment: If you only want a few things, you could parse it **much** more easily than dissect it as a string.

Comment: @Plutonix **How** can i phrase the string to get the **one** value (**my-file.mp3**) ?

Comment: That looks nothing like json. It looks much more like you need an xml parser.

Comment: Also... what you are trying to do is not so much _trim_ the string as _parse_ it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your keyword is `music-file="`

use `InStr()` to find your keyword example:

```
int keyWordPos = InStr(<your string>,<your keyword>)  'keyWordPos = 13
```

you will get the first position of keyword. Next, use it as start position to find the end of value(I mean the second `"` of `music-file="my-file.mp3"`). But, don't forget to add keyword length to skip the first `"`. Like this.

```
int endWordPos = Instr(keyWordPos + len(<your keyword>),<your string>,<your keyword>)   'Start at 25 and endWordPos = 36
```

After that, use SubString() to get your value.

```
string strVal = <String Variable>.SubString(keyWordPos,endWordPos - keyWordPos + 1)
```

Here the answer of mine.

```
string strText = "type='game' music-file='my-file.mp3' gts='false'"
string keyWord = "music-file='"
int keyWordPos = Instr(strText,keyWord)   'Should be 13
int endWordPos = Instr(keyWordPos + len(keyWord),strText,"""") 'Should be 36
string resultText = strText.SubString(keyWordPos,endWordPos - keyWordPos +1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim text As String = "type='game' music-file='my-file.mp3' gts='false'"
text = ((text.Substring(text.IndexOf("music-file"))).Substring(0, (text.Substring(text.IndexOf("music-file"))).IndexOf(" gts="))).Trim
```

Comment: If this is xml/sgml -based source, the order of the attributes will **not** be guaranteed. Even if it's likely to stay consistent as a practical matter, using a dedicated xml parser is the much wiser course.